# потомки $(this)

Tags: html, jquery, css

Повесил на div событие

```
<div onmouseover="tooltipHide(this)">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="name-action">
    <ul>
     <li>
      <a>
       <div class="tooltip-custom">
```

пытаюсь найти элемент `.tooltip-custom` в таблице стилей задан `{display:none}` внутри `DIVа` по классу:

```
function tooltipHide(el) {      
    var child = $(this).find('div.tooltip-custom');
    child.attr('style', 'display:block');
};
```

реакции нет, блок остается скрытым
подскажите как обратиться к элементу?

Comment: а где ошибка? приведенная строка вполне себе объект `jQuery`. Добавьте в вопрос функцию `tooltopHide`, а также разметку к которой это все применяется

Comment: Это не ошибка, а результат поиска.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

В конструкции `<div onmouseover="tooltipHide(this)">` функция `tooltipHide` вызывается в глобальном контексте (`this` внутри функции - это `window`). Используйте элемент, который Вы передали в функцию `tooltipHide`, для поиска внутри него:

```
function tooltipHide(item) {
  var child = $(item).find('.tooltip-custom');
  console.log(child); 
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, есть результат